# Family sharing and iCloud

Tags: icloud

I just set up family share and my account is listed in my son's iCloud settings. How do I change this so he is the primary account on his device?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on iOS 8

> Create separate Apple ID for each family member. Use this Apple ID to
> create individualized iCloud accounts. Use each account as the primary
> iCloud account on each family members device.
>
> Choose which family member will be the family organizer. From within the Settings app on that family members device, tap on iCloud > Family Sharing > Get Started.
>
> Sign into the Apple ID that will be used for iTunes and App Store purchases. You may be prompted to validate your accounts payment options.
>
> Choose whether or not you’d like to share your location with your family.
>
> Tap on “Add Family Member…” to start adding up to six additional iCloud accounts to your family share.

[source](https://gigaom.com/2014/10/04/thinking-about-switching-to-ios-8s-new-family-sharing-heres-what-you-need-to-know/)

[more information here](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201084)